# Jquery ajax success response is string not javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm making a jQuery AJAX call to my Rails app (all run on localhost) which is responding with Javascript.  The javascript is running because I'm getting the alert.  But, I would like to read the my_var variable in the js.erb file.  However, when I try to look at the data parameter of the success function it sees the data as a string. So doing data.my_var is undefined.

js.erb file

```
var my_var = "hi";
alert('this ran');
```

javascript

```
  $.ajax({
      url: "/a/validate?a_id=" + "<%= params[:id] %>",
      context: this,
      dataType: "script",
      data:
      {
        json_a: JSON.stringify(this.a),
        model_to_validate: model,
        target_class: target_class,
        current_class: current_class
      },
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(!this.orderFormViewed) {
          this.orderFormViewed =  data.order_block_opened;
        }
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log("error in ajax validate call");
        debugger;
      }
    })
```

Comment: You're expecting a script according to the dataType, why would it be an object ?

Answer (score 1):

try to change your `dataType` to `json` if you only need to get an object and be sure your server return a json.

Comment: This won't be sufficient, as what is being returned isn't actually json, the response needs to change too.

Answer (score 1):

That's because that's exactly what you told it to do with `dataType: "script"` - look at the `dataType` options below.  The script is run in it's own context and so you won't see that variable (I believe).  You're going to need to communicate differently if you want that set.  Or if you just need data send `json`.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

"script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.